# Why do we need these two lemmas to prove this corollary?

Tags: real-analysis, natural-numbers

Terence Tao in his book *Analysis I* defines addition of two natural numbers like so:

1. $0 + m := m$
2. $ (n{++}) + m := (n+m){++}$

And later proves these two Lemmas:

Lemma 2.2.2: For any natural number $n$, $n + 0 = n$

Lemma 2.2.3: For any natural number $n$ and $m$, we have $n + (m++) = (n+m) ++$

And later goes on to say "As a particular corollary of Lemma 2.2.2 and Lemma 2.2.3 we see that $n++=n+1$ (why?).".

This can be achieved using the Lemmas by setting $m=0$ on Lemma 2.2.3 and using Lemma 2.2.2 after that but couldn't it also be done without these Lemmas?

*Proof.* We use induction. The base case $n=0$ is true by the definition of the number $1$. Suppose inductively that the statement is true for $n$ i.e., $n++=n+1$ and we want to show that $(n++)++=(n++)+1$. By the I.H. the LHS can be written as $(n+1)++$ and by the definition of additon we can write RHS as $(n+1)++$. Which completes our induction. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

This is my first encounter with books that rigorously prove all results and it felt weird to me why Tao chose to mention this corollary after the two lemmas and not before since *if my proof is correct* he could have mentioned it earlier. From the nature of this book and its axiomatic approach this threw me off, so either my proof is false or this isn't very important.

Comment: Is it not number 2 from my list at the top for $m=1$?

Comment: Is the proof you give not just a special case of the proof of Lemma 2.2.3?

Comment: You are right but still, is it essentially the same thing? Because I still didn't use Lemma 2.2.2.

Comment: That Text Book has the Answer : Tao keeps saying **"We do not yet know that $a+b=b+a$ ...."** , whereas , these lemmas are inverting the Definitions. When you are giving your Alternate Proof , you should try writing it completely & ensuring that you are not inverting the Order !

Comment: Did I invert the order anywhere? I can't find where if that's the case.

Comment: That was the last sentence in my Comment : You should write it out , not give it in outline : Even if that Point is not true here , it will assist in figuring out what other shortcomings are there !

Comment: The base case for $n=0$ says that $0++=0+1$ and by the definition of addition $0+1=0$ so the base case is $0++=1$ which is true by the definiton of $1$. Suppose it is true for $n$ i.e., $n++=n+1$ and want to show $(n++)++=(n++)+1$. By the I.H. $(n++)++=(n+1)++$. By definition of addition for $m=1$ we get $(n++)+1=(n+1)++$. So the LHS and RHS are equal. --Is this what you meant when saying "writing it completely"? I don't see anything wrong with this proof either. Did you see anything wrong? Or was the last comment general?

Comment: Can someone please explain the two plusses notation?  $ (n{++}) + m := (n+m){++}$ ?? I have not seen this before and have no idea what it means.

Comment: $n++$ is the increment or successor of $n$. For example $2++=3$, $3++=4$ etc.

Comment: Oh right, like in programming, got ya. Normally the successor to $m$ is written $S(m).$

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your proof (assuming that $1$ has been defined to be $0{++}$, and that the axiom of induction has been stated using the ${++}$ operator). It is generally the case that there are many different routes through the development of a formal theory. Tao just chose a different route from you.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: yes, it is unusual notation in the mathematical logic context. In C and C++, $i{++}$ means something much more horrendous than $i + 1$ (its value is $i$, but it has the side-effect of incrementing $i$, so the next time you read $i$, you'll get what was $i + 1$).

Comment: Yes I know it is the incrementing operator/function. Haven't done programming in a while so I didn't recognise it. It's the same in Python and probably other languages also.

Comment: Yup, $1$ is defined to be $0$’s successor and that’s how induction is defined. A small note about the increment operator; on Tao’s book the  operator is two plus signs that are combined and don’t have a gap as I’ve made them here. I’ve also seen it represented as $n^{+}$ which I might even prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is anything wrong with your proof. He could have chosen to write the corollary as a lemma before $2.2.2$ and $2.2.3$ and it will still make sense. It is a corollary here because it follows almost immediately from $2.2.2$ and $2.2.3$. Corollary does not mean that the result cannot be proven without its preceding theoreom/proposition/lemma as you have shown.

Comment: I don't know book's Tao but it would be possible that within a rigurous formalism it is "forbidden" to use induction "now", in this first step.

Comment: Both 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 are proven using induction in Tao's book and he does state the mathematical induction as part of the peano axioms earlier in the book so it should be fine